# Libgdx change TextButton bg alpha

Tags: libgdx

I have this textbuttons where the user can change the colors, now I want the user to be able to change the alpha too.

When I change the alpha of the font textbutton it only affect the font alpha wich is great. `button.getStyle ().fontColor = newColorWithLowAlpha`

But when I change the alpha of the button it affects the font alpha too.`button.setColor(newColorWithLowAlpha)`

Is there a way to change the button alpha without changing the alpha of the text? Thanks

Comment: Change the color of the background in the style, the same way you're changing the font.

Comment: Tenfour04  there is not a variable for backgroundColor in TextButtonStyle, I can get the drawables up, down, checked but I think I cant change the color of a drawable?

Comment: It's called just background. It's a Drawble. You can create a SpriteDrawable to set on it, and tint the SpriteDrawable with its setColor() method.

Comment: Thanks Tenfour04 I will try it when I get home

Comment: Hey tenfour04 thanks it did work I had to use NinePatchDrawable though. Cheers !